# Pop a temporary window with buttons next to clicked element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page (using Bootstrap and AngularJS) with several instances of the same button, each instance relates to a particular element the button is next to.

I want to implement a temporary window that will pop as soon as I click on one of the instances and will include a number of buttons.

For instance, imagine a table with data, each record showing different status and hence the options that will be offered will depend on the status of the record. Also, at the right of each record there is a button giving access to the possible actions on the record. Whenever I click on a button, a small window needs to be shown *next to the clicked button* showing the applicable actions (e.g. "Delete", "Activate", "Retire", etc.).

The size of the temporary window will adjust according to the number of buttons shown.

Comment: Use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ Popovers or Dialogs

Comment: Thank you @Michelem. I am using it for quite many modals. The problem is that I don't quite know how to cause it to be shown next to the clicked button.

Comment: Add some relevant code to play with

Comment: I didn't think this would be resolved with something different from **CODE**. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution (at least, it very well complies with my needs). It is a bootstrap dropdown button into which it is possible to embed a dynamic list of buttons (again, depending on the contents of the record in my example).

So, the HTML would look like:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <button ng-if="Delete"   type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="Delete($index)"   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:100px"><font size="3">Delete  </font></button>
        <button ng-if="Retire"   type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="Retire($index)"   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:100px"><font size="3">Retire  </font></button>
        <button ng-if="Activate" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="Activate($index)" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:100px"><font size="3">Activate</font></button>
        <button ng-if="Promote"  type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="Promote($index)"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="width:100px"><font size="3">Promote  </font></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to those that posted suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="position:relative">
  <button>
    button to be clicked
  </button>
  <div style="position: absolute; display:inline-block; /*width, height, top, bottom*/ these option you need to set"> 
    option1 option 2 option 3 
  </div>
</td>
```

On click of the button hide/show this div. Because the div-Element is absolute to its parent container, it will be always near the button if you give proper attributes.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. Couple of questions though: 1) Why are you using `<td>` (which is the table-data  tag)? 2) Wouldn't this change the layout of the page? What I was looking for is something similar to a tooltip but with elements inside instead of plain text.

Comment: I thought you were using a table and button is in one of the colums

Comment: Yes, but what I want is, when clicking on that button, a pop would be shown displaying a number of buttons, depending on the data of the record. I would prefer to avoid affecting the layout of the table, and hence the pop.